# Total all values of a single property from an object within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, new-operator

```
function player(name, goals, games) {
    this.name = name;
    this.goals = goals;
    this.games = games;
}

var ricky = new player('Ricky', 7, 15);
var tom = new player('Tom', 15, 17);
var phil = new player('Phillip', 9, 14);
var jerry = new player('Jerry', 11, 15);
var randy = new player('Randy', 4, 16);
var sam = new player('Sam', 5, 11);


function locTeams(name, town, wins, playerOne, playerTwo, playerThree) {
    this.name = name;
    this.town = town;
    this.wins = wins;
    this.playerOne = playerOne;
    this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    this.playerThree = playerThree;
}

var tigers = new locTeams('Great Tigers', 'Clayton', 9, ricky, tom);
var pantheon = new locTeams('The Pantheons', 'Brookedale', 8, jerry, randy);

teams = [tigers, pantheon];

var totalGoalsState =
```

I need an easy way to have `totalGoalsState` equal the accumulative player goals from the players in the `teams` array. Also, how do i fill `playerThree` with one of the other new player such as `phil` or `sam` into one of the teams like tigers or pantheons.

Comment: Your constructor for `locTeams` requires 5 parameters, you are passing 4. You miss there as well `this.playerThree = playerThree`.

Comment: @AleksandarĐokić - it doesn't really *require* 5 arguments, it *can have* 5 arguments.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, but he is not setting `playerThree` anywhere in method... He should, since it is in constructor.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add that, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to add up the goals for all the teams in the array, iterating and reducing the values for each player, each team etc.

```js
function player(name, goals, games) {
    this.name = name;
    this.goals = goals;
    this.games = games;
}
function player(name, goals, games) {
    this.name = name;
    this.goals = goals;
    this.games = games;
}

var ricky = new player('Ricky', 7, 15);
var tom = new player('Tom', 15, 17);
var phil = new player('Phillip', 9, 14);
var jerry = new player('Jerry', 11, 15);
var randy = new player('Randy', 4, 16);
var sam = new player('Sam', 5, 11);


function locTeams(name, town, wins, playerOne, playerTwo, playerThree) {
    this.name = name;
    this.town = town;
    this.wins = wins;
    this.playerOne = playerOne;
    this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
    this.playerThree = playerThree;
}

var tigers = new locTeams('Great Tigers', 'Clayton', 9, ricky, tom);
var pantheon = new locTeams('The Pantheons', 'Brookedale', 8, jerry, randy);

var teams = [tigers, pantheon];

function getGoals(team) {
  return Object.keys(team).map(function(k) {
     return k.indexOf('player') === 0 ? 
          team[k] && "goals" in team[k] ? team[k].goals : 0 : 0;
    }).reduce(function(a,b) { return a+b });
}

var totalGoalsState = teams.reduce(function(a,b) {return getGoals(a) + getGoals(b)});

console.log(totalGoalsState)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a third player, just add it where the other two are already. Note that i am eliminating duplicates, as in each player can only count towards total goals once.

```js
function player(name, goals, games) {
    this.name = name;
    this.goals = goals;
    this.games = games;
}

var ricky = new player('Ricky', 7, 15);
var tom = new player('Tom', 15, 17);
var phil = new player('Phillip', 9, 14);
var jerry = new player('Jerry', 11, 15);
var randy = new player('Randy', 4, 16);
var sam = new player('Sam', 5, 11);


function locTeams(name, town, wins, playerOne, playerTwo, playerThree) {
    this.name = name;
    this.town = town;
    this.wins = wins;
    this.playerOne = playerOne;
    this.playerTwo = playerTwo;
}

var tigers = new locTeams('Great Tigers', 'Clayton', 9, ricky, tom);
var pantheon = new locTeams('The Pantheons', 'Clayton', 9, jerry, randy);

teams = [tigers, pantheon];

var totalGoalsState = teams.reduce((p, c) => p.concat([c.playerOne, c.playerTwo]), [])
                           .reduce((p, c) => p.includes(c) ? p : p.concat(c), [])
                           .reduce((p, c) => p + c.goals, 0);

console.log(totalGoalsState);
```